# Thread handle leak in .Net service (Not win32 threads. i.e not observable in Task Manager)

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm trying to debug a handle leak in a .Net service and I'm puzzled by a Thread Handle leak. 
Could someone please describe how this can happen? Task Manager reports only 22 active threads after each test period, but the handle count keeps increasing.

I send a message to force GC after each test period, and before getting the handle count.

There is, of course, an event handle leak also, but that is easier to explain/fix.

```
D:\log\SEEService>handle -p 82080 -s

Handle v3.46
Copyright (C) 1997-2011 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Handle type summary:
  ALPC Port       : 8
  Desktop         : 1
  Directory       : 3
  EtwRegistration : 35
  Event           : 97397
  File            : 36
  IoCompletion    : 3
  Key             : 38
  KeyedEvent      : 1
  Mutant          : 9
  Section         : 23
  Semaphore       : 15
  Thread          : 22845
  Timer           : 5
  Token           : 1
  TpWorkerFactory : 4
  WindowStation   : 2
Total handles: 120426
```

Answer (score 0):

This link might still be relevant: [Thread handle leak](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/430646/thread-handle-leak). Have you tried calling `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` after `GC.Collect()`?

Comment: I found the bug :)

I removed one and one module from the execution path, and found the "bad" module. It was a communication module, and it was the classic "added object to list, but not removed" bug :)

The thread handle ++ was not able to be GC'd because a list held a referense to a object..

Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug :) I removed one and one module from the execution path, and found the "bad" module. It was a communication module, and it was the classic "added object to list, but not removed" bug :) The thread handle ++ was not able to be GC'd because a list held a referense to a object.. Thanks for the reply